# FFmpeg.AutoGen on UWP platform

Tags: visual-studio, dll, ffmpeg, uwp

Is it possible to use the *FFmpeg.AutoGen* packages on UWP (Universal Windows Platform) project?

Answer (score 0):

no, I have looked for the same for the past month but I didn't find anything supporting FFmpeg.autogen directly in uwp but you can use the desktop bridge to launch an exe in the System Tray and ask it to do the work there you can use FFmpeg.autogen

for a system tray example, you can go here:https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP%20Systray

and you can learn about how desktop extension or bridgework and how to package it for the store from here :**https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/**